# Get both cell date and event id

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have an **agendaWeek** view and I'd like to "break" the clicked event and insert another similar event where the start is the corresponding date of the clicked cell and the end is start + X hour. So I need to get both the event id and the date of the clicked cell. Consider that my events can last more than a day so I cannot simply get the event start and end.

I know that **eventClick** can give me the event id while **dayClick** can give me the cell date... I need something to get both these informations.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post an example of the code you've tried that does not work, or link to the docs for the library you're using? It's hard for me to understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately this has been asked many times before and it isn't possible. You'd have to trigger some custom UI to run when the event is clicked and the user will have to specify the break point that way.